# pip cannot confirm SSL certificate: SSL module is not available

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, python-3, pip

I am trying to install openCv for Python 3.6 on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+, but somehow it won't connect to the python.org website. I have pip installed for 2.7, 3.0, and 3.6 installed, so when I go and do something like:

pip3 install opencv-python

I get this error:

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting opencv-python
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/opencv-python/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not fetch URL https://www.piwheels.org/simple/opencv-python/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

I can access the website perfectly on my desktop and phone, but my Raspberry Pi won't at all. Any idea what I can do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi/29751768#29751768

Answer (score 1):

*pip3* missed a certificate for authentication to https://pypi.python.org/simple/opencv-python/ and to https://www.piwheels.org/simple/opencv-python/. On my RasPi (Raspbian Stretch) I found two packages in its repository with `apt list *certi*` that may belonging to it:

```
ca-certificates/stable,now 20161130+nmu1+deb9u1 all [installed]
python3-certifi/stable 2016.2.28-1 all
```

You can try to install them but I don't know if it helps:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo apt install ca-certificates python3-certifi
```

Comment: Not helping, tried it too

Comment: Next thing to check, if certificates are up-to-date, is the system date and time - if it's e.g. far off in the past, the certificates will be rejected.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install following dependencies.

Run in following in your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall 
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libbz2-dev
```

Comment: Yes, I have run these on my terminal

Comment: still after executing the command it is showing the same error

Comment: In that case, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/41601137/6538713